# bootstrap menu - item cut off - for smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm modifying an [existing template](http://www.dzyngiri.com/legend-free-responsive-one-page-template/) that uses Bootstrap.

Here's my work:
http://goo.gl/vbazGv

My problem is that the last item of the menu - contactos - disappears for smaller screens:

[image: image1]

While it's present for bigger ones:

[image: image2]

I think that the changing point is 767px.

I can't for the life of me correct this problem... I have tried everything but can't seem to understand nor find the code that produces this change.

Comment: Can we get some dat CSS?

Comment: I apologise for not sharing any code, but I don't know what to share. That's why I have provided the link to the work. This way all the code becomes immediately available.

Comment: Okay. That's good enough

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem didn't appear for smaller than 767, it appeared for smaller than 979px.
I was able to solve it by increasing the margin-bottom:

```
 @media (max-width: 979px) {
 .navbar .container {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```